# MySQL - странности с индексом и выборкой с IN

Tags: mysql

Таблица на 120к записей.

Индексы: ad_id (PRIMARY), pmask (INT 11), udate (TIMESTAMP)

```html
SELECT ad_id FROM ad WHERE pmask IN (1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,21,22,23,25,26,27,29,30,31,16) AND udate<'2017-03-22 22:18:34' AND publish=1 ORDER BY udate DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Оптимизатор MySQL по умолчанию берет за индекс udate, EXPLAIN Показывает type=range, rows=49225 - но сам запрос выполняется 0,5-0,6 сек - что неприемлемо

Если в запрос добавить FORCE INDEX(pmask) - EXPLAIN выдает type=all, rows=1220425 , но сам запрос выполняется 0,0009 сек

Подскажите что за глюк - проверял на двух хостингах - проблема аналогична

На денвере без FORCE INDEX берет по умолчанию индекс pmask и запрос летает
EXPLAIN type=range, rows=25

Comment: для это собственно и существуют подсказки оптимизатору, что бы обходить такие моменты. план выполнения зависит от количества записей в таблицах, их содержимого и от версии MySQL. так что это не глюк а обычное поведение любой СУБД. Идеального оптимизатора не существует в природе. Это примерно как погоду предсказывать, прогнозы боле менее верные, но периодически никуда не годятся

Comment: что оптимизатор тупит давно известно - странно другое - без force (type=range, rows= 49 225) время 0,6 сек, а c force (type=all, rows= 1 220 425) - время 0,0009

Comment: А сколько реально записей в БД с указанными в IN pmask ?

Comment: Пока 30 записей из 120к - только обороты набираем - остальные 0 по умолчанию. Со временем их будет 10-20% - не больше - от общего числа записей. Думаете поэтому оптимизатор этот индекс не берет?

Comment: Ну да. оптимизатор не знает сколько таких записей будет. И ясно, что сортировка 30 записей которые, находятся по индексу, мгновенно проходит. А когда записей окажется много - тогда как раз тот индекс с датой может оказаться более селективным и главное, сортировать не понадобится, если оптимизатор догадается в обратном порядке пойти